# Alert Dialogue Box inside column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]In my app users are required to submit their government ID's for verification to keep using the app. On the basis of the condition "isIDverified" it displays a text "Verified" or if it's under review it displays "Under Review". Inside the verified condition I want to put a popup which will say "Your account is under review" along with the text somewhere around this green empty block.

My code:

```
    if (isIDVerified) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Verified',
            style: kAppBarTitleTextStyle.copyWith(color: primaryColor),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: _screenUtil.setWidth(10),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.verified_user,
            size: kPreferredIconSize,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else if (isIDUnderReview) {
      return
        Text(
        'ID Under Review',
        style: kAppBarTitleTextStyle.copyWith(color: primaryColor),
        
      );
```

Comment: what do you mean by you want to add a popup? how should it be shown? do you have any mock how you want it to be shown?

Comment: updated post, please check.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to answer it. 
For displaying popups, you can make use of AlertDialogs. 
You can do something like this.

```
void informUser() {
    
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
             title: new Text("Under Review"),
             content: Column(
                 children: [ LIST OF WIDGETS ]
             ),
             actions: <Widget>[
               new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("Close"),
                  onPressed: () {
                         Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
             ],
          );
        },
     );

  }
```

You can put your widgets in the `Column` widget of `AlertDialog`'s `content`.